# Where have I gone wrong in computing the integral closure of $k[X, Y, Z]/(Y^3 + Y^2X^2 + YX^2 + X^3Z)$?

Tags: solution-verification, commutative-algebra, fake-proofs

I was trying to follow the strategy in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1058025/326036) to compute the integral closure of the domain $$R := k[X, Y, Z]/(Y^3 + Y^2X^2 +  YX^2  + X^3Z)$$ where $k$ is a field.
During the computation, I realized I could tweak one of the arguments to reach an absurd conclusion, while the end conclusion is still true. So I'm wondering what is wrong in the proof below.

> Let $f = Y^3 + Y^2X^2 +  YX^2  + X^3Z$.
> Let $x, y, z$ denote the images of the free variables $X, Y, Z$ in the quotient.
> Note that $t := \frac{y}{x}$ is integral over $R$ as we have $t^3 + t^2x + t + z = 0$. My claim is that $S := R[t]$ is the integral closure of $R$.
>
> Indeed, consider the surjective homomorphism $\phi: A = k[X, Y, Z, T] \to S$ given by $X \mapsto x$, $Y \mapsto y$, $Z \mapsto z$ and $T \mapsto t$, which exists by the universal property of polynomial rings.
> Since $S$ is an integral domain, $\ker \phi$ is a prime ideal of $A$.
> Moreover, we have $\dim A = 4$ and $\dim S \ge 3$, since
> $$(f) \subsetneq (X, Y + X^2) \subsetneq (X, Y) \subsetneq (X, Y, Z) $$
> is a chain of prime ideals in $k[X, Y, Z]$ containing $f$ of length 3, so by the correspondence theorem it corresponds to a chain of primes in $R$, which by the going-up theorem can be extended to a chain in $S$.
> The height of $\ker \phi$ satisfies:
> $$\dim(A) - h(\ker \phi) \ge \dim (A/\ker \phi) = \dim S \ge 3$$
> So we have that $h(\ker \phi) \le 4 - 3 = 1$.
> But $\ker \phi$ is nonzero, as it contains e.g. $TX - Y$, and $A$ is a domain, so its height is exactly 1.
>
> We clearly have $(TX - Y) \subseteq \ker \phi$, and since the latter is a prime ideal of height one and the former is a nonzero ideal in a domain, it suffices to prove that $(TX - Y)$ is prime to conclude $(TX - Y) = \ker \phi$.
> And indeed:
> $$A/(TX - Y) = k[X, Y, Z, T]/(TX - Y) \cong k[X, Z, T]$$
> which is a domain.

Now, this is the absurd conclusion, since $\ker \phi$ contains elements outside of $(XT - Y)$, such as $T^3 + T^2X + T + Z$. What is wrong in the above argument?

However, the final conclusion still holds, I've checked that $S$ is indeed the integral closure of $R$.

> This last equation also tells us that $S \cong k[X, Z, T]$ which is a UFD, hence integrally closed.
> Since we have $R \subseteq S \subseteq \mathrm{Frac}(R)$ and $S$ is integral over $R$, we conclude that $S$ is the integral closure of $R$.

Comment: In M2 `R=QQ[x,y,z,w]` `I=ideal(y^3*w + y^2*x^2 + y*x^2*w + x^3*z)`` primaryDecomposition integralClosure(R/I,QQ) -- {subquotient(matrix {},matrix {{w_(1,0)*y-x*z, w_(1,1)*x+x^2+y*w, w_(1,0)*x-w_(1,1)*y+x*w, w_(1,1)^2-x^2+w_(1,0)*w-y*w+w^2, w_(1,0)*w_(1,1)+w_(1,1)*y-x*w+z*w, w_(1,0)^2-w_(1,1)*z+w_(1,0)*w}})}` `F=icMap(R/I)` `conductor F -- ideal(y^2,x*y,x^2)`

Comment: From the equation $zx^3+y^3+y^2 x^2+y x^2=0$ we see it represents a quartic surface in ${\Bbb A}^3$, viewable in geogebra over the reals as $z=-\frac{y^3+y^2 x^2+y x^2}{x^3},$ singular along the line $x=y=0$ ($x=0$ intersect triply in this) .The point $(0,0,l)$ has tangent cone $lx^3+x^2y+y^3,$ which over the complexes has three linear factors. The line $y=z=0$ is also on the surface.

Comment: $\dim S=\dim R=2$. Moreover, $S$ is isomorphic to a polynomial ring in *two* variables over $k$ since $R[t]=k[x,y/x]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a theorem in algebraic geometry that an affine variety in $\mathbb{A}^n$ is of dimension $n - 1$ if and only if it is cut out by a single polynomial.
Since $R$ satisfies this criterion, we have $\dim R = 2$.
Moreover, integral extensions don't change the dimension, so $\dim S = \dim R = 2$.

My mistake was in writing the chain of prime ideals:

> $ \cdots \subsetneq (X, Y + X^2) \subsetneq (X, Y) \subsetneq \cdots$

This inclusion is not strict, as they're the same ideal.
Therefore the chain of prime ideals has length 2, so if I continued my argument from there I would get $h(\ker \phi) \le 2$.

Then, we could argue that the following is a chain of length 2 of prime ideals in $A$ contained in $\ker \phi$:
$$ (0) \subsetneq (XT - Y) \subsetneq (XT - Y, T^3 + XT^2 + T + Z)$$
Since $\ker \phi$ has length at most 2, we conclude that $\ker\phi = (XT - Y, T^3 + XT^2 + T + Z)$.
If we compute the quotient $A/\ker\phi$, we get $S \cong A/\ker\phi \cong k[X, T]$, and now we can use the same argument I used at the end above to finish the proof.