# Certain generators for the normalization of the cuspidal cubic $x^3=y^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X=V(X^3-Y^2)$ the cuspidal cubic over an algebraically closed field $k$.

This variety $X$ has a singularity at $(0,0)$ and this fact is reflected in the coordinate ring as $A=k[X,Y]/(X^3-Y^2)=k[x,y]$ being not normal. The normalization of this ring (i.e the integral closure in the fraction field) is given by $A[\frac{y}{x}]$ as is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500315/working-out-the-normalization-of-mathbb-cx-y-x2-y3).

I want to write $A[\frac{y}{x}]$ as a quotient of the polinomial ring $A[Z]$ by an ideal $I$ in order to find an embedding of $\text{spec}(A[\frac{y}{x}])$ in $\mathbb{A}^3$ (given by $V(I)$) and a natural map $\text{spec}(A[\frac{y}{x}])\rightarrow \text{spec}(A)=X$ induced by $A\rightarrow A[Z]/I$.

For this I need to compute the kernel of the map $A[Z]\rightarrow A[\frac{y}{x}]$ given by $z\mapsto \frac{y}{x}$ but I can't do this. I have noticed that this kernel contains the ideal $(Zx-y,Zy-x^2)$ but I think this is not the entire kernel because the variaty $V(X^3-Y^2,ZX-Y,ZY-X^2)$ is still singular at 0.

Does someone has any idea in how to proceed here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The equation of integrality for $y/x$ over $A$, $Z- x^2$, needs to be in the kernel.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524157/how-does-the-failure-of-integral-closure-of-a-coordinate-ring-relate-to-the-cusp/2538903#2538903) may be helpful.