# If $x^3 = y^2$, why is $y/x$ transcendental?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, commutative-algebra, alternative-proof

Let the ring $A=\mathbb{k}[x,y]/(x^3-y^2)$, and set $t = \frac{y}{x}$. We can form the subring $\mathbb{k}[t]\subset \operatorname{Frac}(A)$, the smallest ring containing $t$. We have identities like $t^2=x$ and $t^3 = y$.

Now - why is $\mathbb{k}[t]$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{k}[X]$ - the ring of polynomials in one variable? In other words, how we know that for any non-zero polynomial $p\in \mathbb{k}[X]$, $p(t)\neq 0$, i.e. $t$ is transcendental?

Motivation:

1. The question is motivated by another question, [about the normalization of A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500315/working-out-the-normalization-of-mathbb-cx-y-x2-y3), in which was determined that the normalization of $\widetilde{A}$ is indeed equal to $\mathbb{k}[t]$. In there, the author of the question explicitly states in the comments that $t$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb{k}$, but with no proof. So the proof should trivial, but still I don't see it.
2. I think I *have* a proof of this fact, but it is unnecessarily complicated. I'm looking for a one-sentence proof. Nevertheless, I would be really thankful for a proof verification.
   Let $w\in \mathbb{k}[T]$ be a polynomial such that $w(t) = 0$ in $\mathbb{k}[t]$. It is of the form $$ w(T) = a_n T^n + \cdots+ a_1 T + a_0 $$
   Using the definition of $t$, I make a polynomial $w' \in \mathbb{k}[X,Y]$
   $$ w'(X,Y) = a_n Y^n + a_{n-1} Y^{n-1} X + \cdots +a_1 Y X^{n-1} + a_0 X^n $$
   so that $w'(x,y) = x^n w(t) $ in $A$. Therefore $w'(x,y) = 0$. It means that $w' \in \ker p$, where $p$ is a natural projection $p: \mathbb{k}[X,Y] \to \mathbb{k}[x,y]/(x^3-y^2)$, so we have $w'(X,Y) = (X^3-Y^2)v(X,Y)$ for $v \in \mathbb{k}[X,Y]$. So we have a factorization
   $$ a_n Y^n + a_{n-1} Y^{n-1} X + \cdots + a_1 Y X^{n-1} + a_0 X^n = (X^3 - Y^2)v(X,Y)$$
   Assuming $a_n \neq 0$ we see that $-a_0 Y^{n-2}$ should be among addends of $v$ (by comparing coefficients). Then we would have $-a_0 Y^{n-2} X^3$ in the product $(X^3-Y^2)v(X,Y)$. But the coefficient in $w'$ before the $Y^{n-2} X^3$ term is $0$, so to cancel it, we need either 
   $$-a_0 Y^{n-4} X^3$$ or
   $$a_0 Y^{n-2}$$ term in $v(X,Y)$. 
   But it cannot be the latter - we already determined the coefficient before $Y^{n-2}$ to be $-a_0$. So it must be $-a_0 Y^{n-4} X^3$. But then, analogously, we get $-a_0 Y^{n-4} X^6$ that need to be canceled in the product.  Continuing like this, after $\lceil{\frac{n}{2}}\rceil$ steps we no longer could form the term for canceling, because the exponent would need to be negative. That leads to contradiction.

Comment: Your proof is "unnecessarily complicated" indeed. The approach is natural, but why don't try the following substitution $X\to T^2$ and $Y\to T^3$ in $$ a_n Y^n + a_{n-1} Y^{n-1} X + \cdots + a_1 Y X^{n-1} + a_0 X^n = (X^3 - Y^2)v(X,Y) $$ This gives you immediately $a_i=0$ for all $i$.

Comment: @user26857 Thank you, that technique will certainly be useful to me in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$t^2 = x$ and $x$ is transcendental; if $t$ were algebraic over $\mathbb{k}$, so would $x$.

$x$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{k}$ in $A$ because $X$ is transcendental in $\mathbb{k}[X]$ and there's a map $A\to \mathbb{k}[X], x\mapsto X^2, y\mapsto X^3$.

Comment: How we know that $x$ is transcendental in A?

Comment: @mzg147: Every multiple of $x^3-y^2$ must have positive degree in $y$ and thus no polynomial involving just $x$ vanishes in $A$.

Comment: @mzg147 : here's another slick proof : consider $\mathbb{k}[x,y]\to \mathbb{k}[X], x\mapsto X^2,  y\mapsto X^3$. Then this factors through $A\to \mathbb{k}[X]$, and $x\mapsto X^2$, $X^2$ being transcendental over $\mathbb{k}$, so is $x$ over $\mathbb{k}$ in $A$

Comment: Thank you. Please add this to your answer, so I can mark it as answered.